# Python BeautifulSoup Span Scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape fields within a Span ID, but the value is not as simple as using find and taking the text from a span.

Below is the HTML from the webpage.
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w19gF.png)

I am trying to print "B0C4YKLXPQ"

This gets me the

Below are all attempts that failed.

```
- page_soup.find("div", {"id": "twisterContainer"}).find_all("data-asin")

- page_soup.find("div", {"id": "twisterContainer"}).find("span", {"id": "fitRecommendationsSection"}).span["data-asin"]

- page_soup.find("div", {"id": "twisterContainer"}).find("span", {"id": "fitRecommendationsSection"}).find_all("data-asin")

- page_soup.find("div", {"id": "twisterContainer"}).find_all("data-asin")

- page_soup.find("div", {"id": "twisterContainer"}).find_all(["data-asin"])
```

Comment: What's the page url?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002G9UDYG

Comment: Pretty sure that issue is not in beautifulsoup but in getting the HTML. Do you actually get the full HTML page in python the same as in your browser?

Comment: Yes, I am able to get the full page without any problems and I was successful in getting  12 other values from this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code has good chances of working, unless your IP has been blacklisted by Amazon for some various reasons, like too many scraping attempts:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B002G9UDYG'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')

item = soup.select_one('span[id="fitRecommendationsSection"]').get('data-asin')
print(item)
```

Result in terminal:

```
B0C4YKLXPQ
```

BeautifulSoup documentation can be found [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: OMG! That worked. You are a freaking GURU!

Comment: Thank you so much. I have spent hours on this. lol.